# What ( 's ) is doing in "What do you reckon's next?"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> "*What do you reckon's next*?" ... ...

I don't understand why ***'s*** is used in this sentence? Does it denote anything? I think ***What do you reckon next?*** is good enough. Any thoughts?

-- Excerpted from Harry Potter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [contraction of "is"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/'s):

> What do you reckon [i]s next?

Without it, the sentence doesn't sound idiomatic. The sentence is using the ["informal [with clause]"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reckon) definition of reckon, so without a verb it's not a clause.

Comment: So, is it ok to add a 'that'? as: "What do you reckon that is next?"

Comment: @dan The sentence with "that" doesn't sound right to me. It sounds like you're asking "What do you reckon *that thing* is?", (i.e. I'm interpreting "that" as a pronoun).

Comment: Ok. Is it similar to say: *What do you reckon happens next?* or *What do you reckon will happen next?*